# SQL job to regularly export all stored procedures to file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, export, backup, sql-server-2014

As a secondary precaution to doing regular SQL backups on our SQL Server, I'd like to be able export all stored procedures, functions and triggers to a file.  That way, in case of something truly catastrophic, we at least have all of our code stored separately.  I know that I can generate these scripts manually through SSMS and its export wizard.  However since our code can potentially change quite often, I'd like to be able set up a nightly job to export all procedures to a .sql file so that we'd always have the most recent copies.

I've done some searching and can't seem to find or figure out a way to automate this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for your source control software, if I am honest. If you have your objects in your source control, which you should, then provided you have a backup of that too you're "quids in".

Comment: And, if you aren't source controlling your objects, this sounds like an excellent reason to do so.

Comment: @Larnu Completely agreed.  Unfortunately though in our environment, we aren't currently managing source control for SQL.  Outside of SQL, yes.  But not for SQL itself.  That's why I'm looking for a hacky alternative.

Comment: The non-hacky alternative would be to get it into Source Control though, @WAM . Rather than reinventing the wheel, why not use the tools that already exist to do exactly this?

Comment: @Larnu Do you have a suggestion for a good free tool to manage SQL source control? I'm open to recommendations.

Comment: [so] isn't the place for tool recommendations, I'm afraid . You'll find a wealth of solutions out there if you search. Some use your database project in Visual Studio/Azure Data Studio, some integrate directly into SSMS. Some come with extra tools (at a cost) too, which help with migrations from Dev/Testing/Production, etc. Which you use really depends on your use case, budget (if any), your existing work flows, and your development environment(s).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your advice.  I'll investigate.

Comment: _That way, in case of something truly catastrophic_ You need a disaster recovery plan for your entire organization - not just SQL code. One that is documented, known, taught, validated, and verified as working on a periodic basis. If that were the case, then you don't need this process for just "stored procedures, functions, and triggers" (which is a big understatement as far as your database is concerned).

Comment: @SMor We do have disaster recovery in place for all systems.  However, most of our recent critical changes have been in our SQL stored procedures (of which there are many) so I'm particularly sensitive to potential loss.  We're already backing them up.  I was just looking for a secondary option on top of the current one in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the procedure definitions from a query against `sys.sql_modules`, and export the query results using BCP. But yeah, source control would be nicer. You could of course export via bcp and add a few git commands to push the output file.

Here I am joining `sql_modules` to `procedures` to limit the query only to stored procedure definitions to demonstrate the technique, but you could get other modules as well if you wanted. And of course you can add other filters... by schema, whatever.

```
bcp "select definition from sys.sql_modules m join sys.procedures p on p.object_id = m.object_id" queryout f:\procs.txt -SMyServer -dMyDatabase -T -c
```

This command will use integrated security (`-T`). You can use SQL auth instead. the `-c` is a shortcut for "character data with tab as the column separator (irrelevant here since we're only getting a single column) and \r\n as the row separator"

Stick that in a sql agent job with cmdexec as the step type, schedule as desired.